# localization in crowd environment

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, laser-filters, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I'm trying to figure out how to achieve robust navigation in crowded environment.
I'm using a 2-d laser scanner and *amcl* algorithm. Is somebody facing the same problem?
Are there any other stacks/tools in ROS that address this situation?

My idea is to filter people and other moving objects from the scan, setting the occluded rays to max range and then to pass this filtered scan to the *amcl*.
Has anybody already tried this solution? Can anybody give me a hint about it?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10724/localization-in-crowd-environment/) by [luca](https://answers.ros.org/users/564/luca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's substantial scientific literature on this; the short answer is that it's tricky, but good techniques exist. There's no up-to-date ROS package for doing this.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luca](https://answers.ros.org/users/564/luca/) on 2011-09-05**:
could you give me some references?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although this is an old post maybe someone new comes looking for the same information. I have found references of doing this with the name of SLAM and DATMO. This means SLAM with detection and tracking of moving objects.

In this method the people are treated in no different way as any other moving object in the scene and probably this is a better approach as there are significant different objects in indoor and outdoor environments.

You can take a look at the following references:

- Section 8.4 of the book probabilitics robotics by Fox, Thrun and Burgard
- [Markov localization in dynamic environments](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0222v1.pdf) by Fox, Burgard and Thrun
- [Literature review of SLAM and DATMO](http://researchspace.csir.co.za/dspace/bitstream/10204/5457/1/Pancham1_2011.pdf) is a good starting point
- The work by [Wang at the Robotics Institute CMU](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebobwang/publications.html). His 2002, 2003 and thesis project are a valuable resource
- All other references in the work of Pancham specially Montesano, Ortega and Vu PhD thesis

Hope this help anyone who arrives here.

---

Originally posted by [Ibraim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3099/ibraim/) with karma: 101 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9